# Isaacs exercise 5.4 (Character Theory of Finite groups)

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

Any advice/hints how to prove the following statement?

If $G$ is a finite group and $b(G)=\max\{\chi(1); \chi\in \mathrm{Irr}G\}$ is the maximal degree of irreducible characters and $H\leq G$, then $b(H)\leq b(G)\leq [G:H]b(H)$.

A character of $G$ restricted to $H$ may become reducible. A character of $H$ expanded to $G$ may have increased degree. If $V$ is a $\mathbb{C}H$-module, then $\dim_\mathbb{C}V^G=[G:H]\dim_\mathbb{C}V$.

Comment: Pretend you found $\theta \in \operatorname{Irr}(H)$ and $\chi \in \operatorname{Irr}(G)$ with $[\theta,\chi_h] \neq 0$. Compare the degrees of $\chi$, $\theta$, and $\theta^G$.

Comment: This exercise is early, so I should mention: it's **all** Frobenius reciprocity.

Comment: My first comment is very low-tech stuff. a ≤ ab ≤ abc kind of reasoning. The second comment is how to make sure the low tech stuff is relevant (where do $\theta$ and $\chi$ even come from?)

Comment: We have $\deg \theta^G=[G:H]\deg\theta$ and $[\theta,\chi_H]_H=[\theta^G,\chi]_G$, but what significance does $\neq0$ have? It just shows $\theta^G=n \chi+\ldots$ and $\chi_H=m\theta$ for $m,n\in\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: If $\theta^G = n\chi + \dots$ with $n > 0$, then how do the degrees of $\theta^G$ and $\chi$ compare? --- Sneaky thing too, how do the degrees of $\chi$ and $\chi_H$ compare?

Comment: Hmm, $[G:H]\theta(1)\leq n\chi(1)$ and $\chi(1)=\chi_H(1)\leq m\theta(1)$, hence $\chi(1)\leq\frac{mn}{[G:H]}\chi(1)$ so $[G:H]\leq mn$.

Comment: Backwards, I think?

Comment: $\chi(1) \leq n \chi(1) + \dots = \theta^G(1) = [G:H] \theta(1)$, and $\theta(1) \leq n \theta(1) + \dots = \chi_H(1) = \chi(1)$, so $\theta(1) \leq \chi(1) \leq [G:H] \theta(1)$.  [ Unnecessary, but I'll mention, $m=n$ because of Frob Recip. I still use the estimate $1 \leq m$ and $1\leq n$, so it doesn't really matter. ]

Comment: Aha, so we begin by "let $\theta\in\mathrm{Irr}H$, then there exists $\chi\in\mathrm{Irr}G$ with $[\theta^G,\psi]$." Very tricky, your inequalities. Thank you!

Comment: Yes, exactly! If you write it up, I can upvote. :-)

Answer (score 1):

If $\psi\in\mathrm{Irr} H$, then $\deg\psi^G=[G\!:\!H]\deg\psi$, so $\psi^G\neq\!0$ and thus there exists $\chi\in\mathrm{Irr} G$ such that by Frobenius reciprocity $[\psi^G,\chi]= [\psi,\chi_H]\neq0$ (because irreducible characters form an orthonormal basis). Therefore $\psi^G=m\chi+\ldots$ and $\chi_H=n\psi+\ldots$ for some $m,n\in\mathbb{N}$. But then $\chi(1)\leq m\chi(1)+\ldots= \psi^G(1)= [G\!:\!H]\psi(1)$ and $\psi(1)\leq n\psi(1)+\ldots= \chi_H(1)=\chi(1)$, so $\psi(1)\leq\chi(1)\leq[G\!:\!H]\psi(1)$.

Thanks to Jack Schmidt.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the idea above is correct, but it is not a proof of the given statement. You find a bound for **some** $\psi\in$Irr$(H)$ and the respective $\chi\in$ Irr$(G)$.

**The upper bound**. Let $\chi\in$ Irr$(G)$ with a maximal degree. We have $\chi_H$ is a character of $H$, so there is $\psi\in$ Irr$(H)$ such that $[\psi,\chi_H]\ne0$. Therefore, $[\psi^G,\chi]\ne0$ by the Frobenius reciprocity. We have $\psi^G=n\chi+\ldots$ for some $n$. Thus, $b(G)=\chi(1)\le\psi^G(1)=[G:H]\psi(1)\le[G:H]b(H)$.

**The lower bound**. Let $\psi\in$ Irr$(H)$ with a maximal degree. Since $\psi^G$ is a character of $G$, we have $[\psi^G,\chi]\ne0$ for some $\chi\in$ Irr$(G)$. Therefore, $[\psi,\chi_H]\ne0$ by the Frobenius reciprocity. We have, $\chi_H=n\psi+\ldots$ for some $n$ and $b(H)=\psi(1)\le\chi_H(1)=\chi(1)\le b(G)$.